# iOS Bluetooth Keyboard Detection at Runtime

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, bluetooth, iphone-softkeyboard

Is there any way in iOS SDK to detect the presence of an active Bluetooth keyboard? As many well know, when a Bluetooth keyboard is active, the on-screen keyboard does not show, so interface placements might have to change...

Right now I am doing this semi-passively by responding to keyboard events, but those notifications are a little slow to post and don't jive perfectly with my animation code. It would be nice to just have a BOOL somewhere to read on...

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPad: detect if external keyboard is present](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893267/ipad-detect-if-external-keyboard-is-present)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I detect if an external keyboard is present on an iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893267/how-can-i-detect-if-an-external-keyboard-is-present-on-an-ipad)