# display soft keyboard (iPad) when is connected a bluetooth input device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uikeyboard

I'm really bangin' my head because I can't find the way  to show the soft keyboard when there's a bluetooth input device connected to the iPad. I made some search on the web and this is the result:

- a question on stackoverflow with a very short answer [How can I detect if an external keyboard is present on an iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893267/ipad-detect-if-external-keyboard-is-present)
- an application developed by erica sadun for the cydia env http://www.tuaw.com/2010/06/02/hacksugar-bringing-back-the-on-screen-keyboard/

Erica said that the trick is to answer to the system that "There's no hardware keyboard attached". 
I tried to write a category for UIKeyboardImpl and I overrided:

```
- (BOOL)isInHardwareKeyboardMode {
    DEBUG(@"is called");
    return NO;
}
```

But until now I haven't obtained anything. The overrided method is called but there's no soft keyboard. 
Erica also said the application works by dynamic linking but I don't know how can I accomplish it. I don't need to be in the AppStore because this is a private application so I don't bother about rejection.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok. Finally got it. Many thanks to David, Matthias and Enrico. Here are the steps:

- import the private framework GraphicsServices
- call GSEventSetHardwareKeyboardAttached(NO) inside the viewDidLoad
- add a button that toggles the keyboard by calling

  ```
  static void toggleKeyboard(UIKeyboardImpl * keyImpl){
  if (UIKeyboardAutomaticIsOnScreen()) {
      UIKeyboardOrderOutAutomatic();
  } else {
      UIKeyboardOrderInAutomatic();
  }
  ```

I've found this function on http://code.google.com/p/btstack/wiki/iPhoneKeyboardHiding
Now I can take input from the soft keyboard and from the bluetooth device at the same time.

Comment: doesn't using a private framework mean you will get rejected from the iTunes store?

Comment: he said it's a private-use app so he doesn't care.

Comment: Never saw rejects on private API.

Comment: What about for iOS 10 ? any help ?

Answer (score 0):

To get around it using the apple keyboard you hit the eject key. Perhaps you can implement an action that sends the eject keycode? I think iSSH has a feature where you can tap the onscreen keyboard icon to bring it up even when a bluetooth keyboard is connected.