# How can I interact with "iPad keyboard hiding button" programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, ipad

There is a button at bottom right of iPad keyboard which is to hide the keypad.

[image]

How can I interact with it programmatically? (get the button then send `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` to it).

Does anyone know this?

[Edit]
In my case, the keyboard is shown on a modal view.

Comment: is this a different behavior than sending -(void)dismissFirstResponder to the view that you are editing?

Comment: In my case, resignFirstResponder does not work since I want to hide iPad keyboard on a modal view (UIModalPresentationFormSheet) to display UIDatePicker, so I would like to fire that event to hide keypad if possible

Comment: If you present the UIDatePicker and make it the first responder, the keyboard should go away, no?  Why isn't that good enough?

Comment: hi IPMCC, let me try it, thanks

Comment: I was looking for the same thing and this worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6268520

Answer (score 2):

Overriding `disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal` to return `NO` as below allows you to dismiss the keyboard when you `resignFirstResponder`, even when your `UITextView` is on a modal view. You should put this code to your view controller, from which you initiate the keyboard:

```
- (BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal {
    return NO;
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6268520

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? I can't remember where I found this code but I used it to toggle the on-screen keyboard because it would be hidden by default if a bluetooth one was connected.

```
- (void) toggleKeyboard(UIKeyboardImpl * keyImpl){

    if (UIKeyboardAutomaticIsOnScreen()) {
        UIKeyboardOrderOutAutomatic();
    } else {
    UIKeyboardOrderInAutomatic();
}
```

**Edit**

---

I found [where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150724/display-soft-keyboard-ipad-when-is-connected-a-bluetooth-input-device/4178482#4178482) I got this code from. It works fine but the catch is that you need to import the private framework `GraphicsServices`, which would most likely get your app rejected from the App store.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you would send the [`resignFirsResponder`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/resignFirstResponder) message to the active input view.

Comment: I tried this already, but in my case, the keyboard on a modal view does not take effect.