# Programmatically check Bluetooth connections

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, bluetooth

Is there any way to programmatically check the Bluetooth connectivity (and probably the connection strength too) of an iOS device with a Windows notebook? And yes, first of all, is it possible for checking if the device is connected to a Mac as well? What about the same with a Windows machine?

Comment: With the `External.framework`, you can see what's connected to your iDevice (EADemo sample)

Comment: That's just for Bluetooth accessories I suppose, especially for the MFI program. I'm talking about connections to notebooks (Win/Mac).

Comment: Check this     


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893267/how-can-i-detect-if-an-external-keyboard-is-present-on-an-ipad

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150724/display-soft-keyboard-ipad-when-is-connected-a-bluetooth-input-device