# Display virtual keyboard with barcode scanner attached

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

We have written an enterprise app for a wholesaler client. The app directs their warehouse staff to different locations in the warehouse, telling them which products to pick.

The app allows the picker to double check they are picking the correct product by entering the barcode of the product they have picked up. The client has purchased a **USB barcode scanner** that allows them to scan directly into the app. The scanning of the barcode and validation works fine. The problem comes when the picker needs to enter the number of units they have picked up. They can't do it because the **virtual keyboard has been hidden**.

The virtual keyboard is hidden because (I assume) iOS thinks the barcode scanner is a hardware keyboard. Is there a way to force the virtual keyboard to remain on screen?

I have searched, but the various solutions either do not work for **iOS8**, or use **private APIs** (which I've not attempted to implement, as they look pretty ropey).

If this is not solve-able programatically, I am happy to advise the client to use a **different scanner** (I have seen some which seem to have a button press to bring up the virtual keyboard, etc). If you happen to know of a scanner that does this, please advise!

I realise I could use the camera on the device, but I don't think the client will go for this as the device is attached to a forklift and wouldn't be practical to pick up and scan all the time.

**tl;dr**: I'm trying to force the virtual keyboard to stay on screen because it is hidden when the barcode scanner is attached.

Comment: If it's just about numbers to enter, you may want to use custom UIView with buttons? That should be simple, and furthermore, allow you to have a "smaller keyboard" which is sometimes really "big" when you only want tp enter one or two digits.

Comment: That's an interesting idea but I don't think it will work in our case as there are a few other fields (plus the app requires input other screens, e.g. login credentials, etc). Thank you for the suggestion :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150724/display-soft-keyboard-ipad-when-is-connected-a-bluetooth-input-device ?