# Swift 4 show on screen keyboard when bluetooth device attached

Tags: swift, xcode, bluetooth, swift4

I have searched a lot on the internet about this issue, when i connect my bluetooth device to my iPad it hides the on screen keyboard, and by clicking on the textfield the on screen keyboard will not show.

Has anybody managed to show the on screen keyboard while the bluetooth device is connected? In my case it is really important to use the on screen keyboard, while having the bluetooth device connected.

Comment: you may want to take a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150724/display-soft-keyboard-ipad-when-is-connected-a-bluetooth-input-device