# How to enable virtual/soft keyboard while connected to a Bluetooth keyboard/Barcode Scanner for React Native on iOS?

Tags: ios, react-native, barcode-scanner, react-native-ios, ios-bluetooth

I've been researching for quite a while and none of the solutions seemed viable enough. For example: articles as referred within [Force software keyboard on iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44467082/force-software-keyboard-on-ios-10)

Our bluetooth bar code scanner has a button which brings up/down the soft/virtual keyboard, but that's definitely not as user-friendly as having a keyboard popping up when focusing on text input.

Is there anyway to accomodate both virtual/soft keyboard and bluetooth keyboard input on iOS? Thanks!

We've also looked into this which seems promising, [display soft keyboard (iPad) when is connected a bluetooth input device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150724/display-soft-keyboard-ipad-when-is-connected-a-bluetooth-input-device)
but it requires importing of private framework which isn't supported on newer XCode's, and isn't App Store-Ready?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution?