# How to hide the on screen keyboard when external keyboard is connected iPhone compatibility mode on ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, compatibility

I have an iPhone app thats runs on the iPad under compatibility mode.  I have a user that uses an external keyboard with his iPad.  is there a way I can detect that keyboard and not display the on-screen keyboard

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893267/ipad-detect-if-external-keyboard-is-present

Comment: Jacob/ the "question/2893267" is just about detecting a external keyboard.
This question is about how to hide keyboard in his only iPhone APP on the iPad.
I have had same problem in my app.