# How to add Bluetooth keyboard support to iOS application?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, keyboard

How to add Bluetooth keyboard support to iOS application? Just how to catch event when any key was pressed?

Comment: try reading this article http://www.pocketmagic.net/2012/07/bluetooth-and-ios-use-bluetooth-in-your-iphone-apps/#.URzuNWfl8dU

Comment: Linked to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873266/how-to-catch-keyboard-keypress-on-uiview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be useful for you to get started.

[External Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893267/how-can-i-detect-if-an-external-keyboard-is-present-on-an-ipad)

Comment: iOS already supports Bluetooth keyboard. I only need to handle keyboard events.