# How to detect if a bluetooth device is connected

Tags: ios, delphi, bluetooth, keyboard, delphi-xe4

Is there anyway to detect if a HID blue tooth device is connected to the device using Delphi XE5, for an iOS application.
Ideally, I would like to show an indicator light if a scanner is connected or not.

Yes, the scanner is iOS supported and does connect and work as keyboard.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I detect if an external keyboard is present on an iPad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893267/how-can-i-detect-if-an-external-keyboard-is-present-on-an-ipad)

Comment: That's for Xcode, I'm using delphi

Comment: So what? Delphi uses Xcode to produce iOS packages.

Comment: Yes, it uses the same API calls, just with a slightly different syntax.

Comment: So would I just use a wrapper, I'm assuming ?

Comment: So, I can't figure it out. Any people willing to help ?