# Synchronizing Animations in keyboardWillShow keyboardWillHide -- Hardware Keyboard & Virtual Keyboard Simultaneously

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiviewanimation, uikeyboard

#### Preamble

So I have an application featuring a chat section, and I'm synchronizing the animation of the keyboard hiding and showing with the rise and fall of the chat input.

Here's the code I'm using:

SHOW:

```
- (void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {

    NSDictionary *keyboardAnimationDetail = [note userInfo];
    UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve = [keyboardAnimationDetail[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue];
    CGFloat duration = [keyboardAnimationDetail[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] floatValue];

    NSValue* keyboardFrameBegin = [keyboardAnimationDetail valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey];
    CGRect keyboardFrameBeginRect = [keyboardFrameBegin CGRectValue];

    // working for hardware keyboard
    //UIViewAnimationOptions options = (UIViewAnimationOptions)animationCurve;

    // working for virtual keyboard
    UIViewAnimationOptions options = (animationCurve << 16);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0.0 options:options animations:^{
        textView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - keyboardFrameBeginRect.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width, -40);
    } completion:nil];

}
```

HIDE:

```
- (void) keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)note {

    NSDictionary *keyboardAnimationDetail = [note userInfo];
    UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve = [keyboardAnimationDetail[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue];
    CGFloat duration = [keyboardAnimationDetail[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] floatValue];

    // hardware keyboard
    //UIViewAnimationOptions options = (UIViewAnimationOptions)animationCurve;

    // virtual keyboard
    UIViewAnimationOptions options = (animationCurve << 16);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0.0 options:options animations:^{
        textView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width, -40);
    } completion:nil];

}
```

This works great with the virtual keyboard, but if keyboardWillShow: or keyboardWillHide: is called as a result of disconnecting or connecting a hardware keyboard, the animation lags. I can fix this by changing the UIViewAnimationOptions

Replace:

```
// Works with virtual keyboard
UIViewAnimationOptions options = (animationCurve << 16);
```

With:

```
// working for firstResponder keyboard
UIViewAnimationOptions options = (UIViewAnimationOptions)animationCurve;
```

But with this, now the virtualKeyboard animation lags

I realize that hardware keyboard animations aren't very common and it's perhaps not the most important issue, but I like everything to just work!

#### Examples

VirtualKeyboard w/ (animationCurve << 16) -- WORKING

[image: VirtualKeyboard w/ (animationCurve << 16)]

VirtualKeyboard w/ (UIViewAnimationOptions)animationCurve -- BROKEN

[image: VirtualKeyboard w/ (UIViewAnimationOptions)animationCurve]

HardwareKeyboard w/ (animationCurve << 16) -- BROKEN

[image: HardwareKeyboard w/ (animationCurve << 16)]

HardwareKeyboard w/ (UIViewAnimationOptions)animationCurve -- WORKING

[image: HardwareKeyboard w/ (UIViewAnimationOptions)animationCurve]

#### Notes

To simulate hardware keyboard in simulator cmd + shft + k

Yes, this is replicable on real device.

In case you want it, here's the rest of my code, just for replication purposes

ADD TEXT VIEW

```
textView = [UITextView new];
textView.layer.borderWidth = 10;
textView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
textView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width, -40);
[self.view addSubview:textView];

UITapGestureRecognizer * tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]init];
[tap addTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];

// OBSERVE KEYBOARD
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

HANDLE TAP:

```
- (void) handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap {
    NSLog(@"tapped");
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
}
```

## The Question:

What is going on here, and is there a good way to get consistent animation regardless of virtual / hardware keyboard?

I realize this is long, thank you for reading!

Comment: Your question is very long and hard to understand dude. Try removing the unnecessary parts to increase the readability.

Comment: What would you suggest I cut?  I want to provide all of the necessary code and explanation for people to replicate the problem, and I included the visuals so people could see what I'm talking about.  I understand it's long, but I think its mostly relevant information.

Comment: Same problem here, if you find your solution then please post it here.

Comment: You might solve it by listening for hardware keyboard connection (depends on the timings, i didn't check): http://stackoverflow.com/a/2893327/653513 - and use appropriate animation according to the type of keyboard. It's a private API though - so it could serve just as proof-of-concept.

Comment: @Logan: How did you capture those nifty animated gifts?

Comment: @RicardoSánchez-Sáez - I use licecap, it's pretty great!  http://www.cockos.com/licecap/

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: @Logan looks like the problem is with the way you specify animation curve: correct way to do is ```UIViewAnimationOptions options = animationCurve;```, and if you specify some options together - use binary OR: ```options = op1 | op2 | op3;```

Comment: @OlegShanyuk thanks for commenting, but that's not really related to the underlying curve issue here and how that specifically pertains to digital/hardware keyboard animation.

Answer (score 3):

Since the animation curve Apple sends you in the keyboard notification does not have a corresponding UIViewAnimationOption bit, you need to drop down to old-school non-block animations and use the curve directly:

```
NSTimeInterval duration = [note.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
UIViewAnimationCurve curve = [note.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue];
[UIView beginAnimations:@"SomeAnimationID" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:curve];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
// Animation code
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Adlai, I've got a couple things to work on at the moment, but I'll try this later today and let you know if it solved the problem.

Comment: Hi @Adlai, thanks for the answer.  I was unable to get this to work. Have you tested it, or was it just an idea?

Comment: I've tested it and it works well for me. What animation code are you using?

Comment: Exactly what's in the question. I replaced the animation blocks w your code.

Comment: Replace my `// Animation code` comment with your `textView.frame = …` code

Comment: I did exactly that, unfortunately, I'm still getting the same problem.

Comment: I also do have the same problem and the here presented solution also doesn't work for me. Any news on that?

Answer (score -1):

**keyboardWillShow:**

```
NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
CGRect keyboardFrame = [info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
NSTimeInterval duration = [info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
UIViewAnimationCurve curve = [info[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue];

[self layoutIfNeeded];
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0 options:(curve << 20) animations:^{
    [self.keyboardConstraint setConstant:keyboardFrame.size.height];
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
} completion:nil];
```