# In iOS can I check wether input is coming from a bluetooth keyboard or the built in keyboard?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, keyboard, rfid, checkin

I am writing a checkin app that will use a bluetooth RFID scanner to checkin users as they scan. All the scanners that I've found seem to work as bluetooth keyboards. The issue is that there will be other activity going on in the app including typing using the built in keyboard. I want this activity to be uninterrupted by the RFID scanner. So my idea is to check as every character comes in wether it is coming from the built in keyboard or the bluetooth one and if it is from the bluetooth scanner move that to a hidden textfield to be dealt with on a separate thread while the user can continue typing. Is there any way that I can do this?

Comment: Have you looked at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893267/how-can-i-detect-if-an-external-keyboard-is-present-on-an-ipad

Comment: @Keenle yes I saw that question. My difference is that both keyboards will be connected at times and could be typing(providing input from the scanner) at the same time.