# How to know if external keyboard is active in iOS

Tags: ios, keyboard, hardware, ios-bluetooth

I have one UITextView in my iOS project, when user taps in the text view, if using soft keyboard, the notification keyboardWillShow will be called. My question is if user uses an external hardware keyboard such as bluetooth keyboard, is there any way to know when it is active?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2893327/9136962

Comment: Thank you I have verified that if I use simulator the sofewareWillShow will not trigger, but if I use iPad device and connect to bluetooth keyboard it will be called.

Comment: if you are using simulator, you can toggle between device keyboard and mac hardware keyboard by shortcut `cmd+K`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few Functionalities like

1. Camera
2. Push Notifications
3. bluetooth Keyboard

For these, you need to use Real device instead of simulator. I haven't tested bluetooth keyboard functionality in realtime. but i'm pretending it was one of the feature that to be tested on real device.Please Make me correct if i was thinking wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have verified that if I use simulator the sofewareWillShow will not trigger, but if I use iPad device and connect to bluetooth keyboard it will be called. The iOS version is 12